# All combinations of two-way tables

Tags: r, combinations

How can I generate all two way tables from a data frame in **R**?

```
some_data <- data.frame(replicate(100, base::sample(1:4, size = 50, replace = TRUE)))
combos <- combn(names(some_data), 2)
```

The following does not work, was planning to wrap a for loop around it and store results from each iteration somewhere

```
i=1
table(some_data[combos[, i][1]], some_data[combos[, i][2]])
```

Why does this not work? individual arguments evaluate as expected:

```
some_data[combos[, i][1]]
some_data[combos[, i][2]]
```

Calling it with the variable names directly yields the desired result, but how to loop through all combos in this structure?

```
table(some_data$X1, some_data$X2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `combn`, there is the `FUN` argument, so we can use that to extract the 'some_data' and then get the `table` output in an `array`

```
out <- combn(names(some_data), 2, FUN = function(i) table(some_data[i]))
```

---

Regarding the issue in the OP's post

```
table(some_data[combos[, i][1]], some_data[combos[, i][2]])
```

Both of them are `data.frame`s, we can extract as a vector and it should work

```
table(some_data[, combos[, i][1]], some_data[, combos[, i][2]])
                ^^                           ^^
```

or more compactly

```
table(some_data[combos[, i]])
```

#### Update

`combn` by default have `simplify = TRUE`, that is it would convert the output to an array.  Suppose, if we have combinations that are not symmetric, then this will result in different dimensions of the `table` output unless we convert it to `factor` with `levels` specified.  An `array` can hold only a fixed dimensions.  If some of the elements changes in dimension, it result in error as it is an array.  One way is to use `simplify = FALSE` to return a `list` and `list` doesn't have that restriction.

Here is an example where the previous code fails

```
set.seed(24)
some_data2 <- data.frame(replicate(5, base::sample(1:10, size = 50, 
     replace = TRUE))) 
some_data <- data.frame(some_data, some_data2)

out1 <- combn(names(some_data), 2, FUN = function(i)
            table(some_data[i]), simplify = FALSE)

is.list(out1)
#[1] TRUE
length(out1)
#[1] 5460
```

Comment: excellent. Supposing if we then had tables with different dimensions? `some_data2 <- data.frame(replicate(5, base::sample(1:10, size = 50, replace = TRUE)))

some_data <- data.frame(some_data1, some_data2)`

Comment: @user3537951  thanks.  Sorry, your question is not clear

Comment: If we have columns in the df that have different numbers of unique values the resulting tables would then different sizes and the combin yields "Error in out[, i] <- r. At any rate the 2nd half of the answer solved the original issue.

Comment: @user3537951  Glad to know that it solved the problem

Comment: @user3537951 Updated the post